# Base class to derive behaviour from when creating an iterator in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing an iterator for use with a class I have written. The behaviour I want is as for a `std::vector::const_iterator` except for the constructor, incrementing and decrementing i.e. the iterator is a (non-mutable, i.e. not an example of an `OutputIterator`) `RandomAccessIterator`.

I don't really want to define all of the operations on the iterator which are the same as the `std::vector::const_iterator` that it uses. I'd prefer to just derive from a class that already has all of this behaviour but, since `std::vector::const_iterator` doesn't have a virtual destructor and, deriving by inheritance would allow conversion back to the `std::vector::const_iterator`, it isn't suitable to just make my iterator inherit from it.

Is there a template defined (in the standard library ideally) that takes a `RandomAccessIterator` as a template argument and provides virtual member functions for all of the operations that a `RandomAccessIterator` is required to have by calling them on a private member that is passed in to the constructor (i.e. it derives all of the `RandomAccessIterator` operations from its template argument by composition, rather than inheritance)?

To clarify, I'd like to be able to write something like

```
template<class value_type>
class myIterator : public random_access_iterator<std::vector<value_type>::const_iterator>
{
    myIterator(..., std::vector<value_type>::const_iterator base_iterator)
        : random_access_iterator(base_iterator) { ... }
    myIterator& operator++ () derived;
    myIterator& operator++ (int) derived;
    myIterator& operator-- () derived;
    myIterator& operator-- (int) derived;
    myIterator(const myIterator&) = default;
    myIterator(myIterator&&) = default;
    myIterator& operator=(const myIterator&) = default;
    myIterator& operator=(myIterator&&) = default;
};
```

but, I don't know if the `random_access_iterator` template in this example exists or, if so, what it is called.

Comment: Maybe something like boost's `iterator_facade`?

Comment: Take a look at the Boost [iterator_adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such template in the standard.

`boost` has a few that help make iterators.

You should, as a rule, implement your own iterator at least once, then throw it out and use a `boost` solution if you can.

`boost`'s `iterator_fascade` uses CRTP to extract behavior from the derived and base types and does a bunch of the boilerplate work for you.  `iterator_adaptor` might be useful if you are modifying an existing iterator.

Writing a basic CRTP iterator helper is a good idea before relying on a `boost` implementation, as it is educational.

Comment: Thanks. It seems a shame that there isn't one in the standard library already. I'd rather not use boost in this case just because it adds more hassle with more to depend on in what is actually just a small program at the moment so, I'm going to write my own and, at least for now, use that (but, if the application expands and comes to depend use boost elsewhere or, has a non-trivial dependencies elsewhere, I will replace it with boost iterator_adapter and, in general, I will use this in future unless there is a good reason not to).